# Looking up values in a table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to lookup values in an excel table using VBA and having trouble getting it all together. I get most of the way there but my code is not worth posting.

What I need to do is write a function with several parameters:
1. What value to look up
2. What column name to look this up in
3. What other column to return the value from

For example, in a table containing Customer_ID, Last_Name, First_Name: pass it "DoeJohn", "Customer_ID", "First_Name" and have it return John. I am not concerned with duplicate values of what I am looking up, finding the first instance is good enough.

The cell it finds may be text, numeric, or date so it needs to return that.
If it doesn't find a match it should return something that could never be an actual cell value, and my main program will check for that.

Comment: Could you post your code and mention where you get any error message? otherwise, it will be writing code for a given requirement which is not done on this site

Comment: Have you looked into using perhaps Index/Match with Indirect? Can you post an example table with example output (or where you'd like the output to be)?  here's a couple of sites: [1](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/638540-index-indirect-match-functions.html) , [2](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/combine-indirect-and-indexmatch/7fe1042b-bb97-49fc-bfe3-c595113838eb) that may help show indirect with index/match.  You can also enter the index/match as an array formula to use multiple matching criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and I apologize for violating protocol. This is my first time posting after reading here a lot. I could not really clean up my code enough to post something understandable. I have been muddling around with programming since (literally) BASIC but never really got into the finer points. I got this working eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with writing Functions() in vba you could simply have a custom function that contained a few vlookup() functions then organize the output and return it however you want.

Comment: I could use vlookup and would do it that way but would have to supply the column number, which may change. I can use the find function to return a cell, but when I do MyFoundCell.row I get the actual spreadsheet row. I need to find what table row, not absolute row, this is.